# Perspective with folder always visible

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a perspective in an RCP product defined as following:

```
        IFolderLayout bottomLeft = layout.createFolder("bottomLeft",
            IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.65f, layout.getEditorArea());
    bottomLeft.addView(BTracePropertyView.ID);
    layout.getViewLayout(BTracePropertyView.ID).setCloseable(false);

    // IFolderLayout bottomRight = layout.createFolder("bottomRight",
    // IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.25f, "bottomLeft");
    bottomLeft.addView(PROGRESS_VIEW_ID);
    layout.getViewLayout(PROGRESS_VIEW_ID).setCloseable(false);
    bottomLeft.addPlaceholder(BTraceOutlineView.ID);
    bottomLeft.addPlaceholder(NewSearchUI.SEARCH_VIEW_ID);
    bottomLeft.addPlaceholder(BTraceStatView.ID);

    IFolderLayout top = layout.createFolder("top",
            IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.75f, layout.getEditorArea());
    top.addPlaceholder(BTraceView.ID + ":*");
```

The result when launching the app is the one I want with an empty visible folder on the top. This folder will be filled when the user will open a given file (with a given extension) in the RCP app.

My problem is that this folder becomes hidden as soon as one view has been opened in the top folder and then closed. Thus the views in the bottoms folders fills vertically all the space.

How can I have a folder that is always visible even when it's empty ?

Manu

Comment: what is the solution, the link is just redirected to eclipse forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/132801/413469/#msg_413469

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationworkbenchWindowAdvisor class, override method isDurableFolder and return true.
Using this folder will never dispose, even all views displayed in folder get disposed.